# Как увеличить объём выделяемой памяти в qemu

Tags: 1с, virtual, ram, qemu

При любой попытке увеличить память свыше 2047Мб QEMU сообщает, что не поддерживает выделение большего объёма оперативной памяти.
qemu-system-i386: at most 2047 MB RAM can be simulated

А 1С просит 3Gb. Как решить проблему?

Comment: Сперва попробуйте 64-битный QEMU - а вдруг... если нет - меняйте гипервизор.

Comment: Озадачили.
вывод lscpu

Архитектура:i686
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Порядок байт:Little Endian
Виртуализация:VT-x

система x86, и поставить 64-битный qemu?